# In R - if cell value matches a column, return value, else 0 in a new dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

```
B1  B2  total
10  0   10
20  20  40
0   20  20
10  20  30
```

Using the dataframe above, I want to create a new dataframe with the following logic:

Going by rows, if cells (B1:B2) matches d$total, return cell value, else 0.

To look like this

```
B1   B2
10   0
0    0
0    20
0    0
```

What is the best way to do this in R?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn the values to 0 where `total` does not match values in first two columns.

```
df1 <- df[1:2]
df1[df1 != df$total] <- 0
df1

#  B1 B2
#1 10  0
#2  0  0
#3  0 20
#4  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `tidyverse` way:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~ B1, ~ B2, ~ total,
  10,  0,   10,
  20,  20,  40,
  0,   20,  20,
  10,  20,  30
)

df %>%
  mutate(
    B1 = if_else(B1 == total, B1, 0),
    B2 = if_else(B2 == total, B2, 0)
  ) %>%
  select(B1, B2)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>      B1    B2
#>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1    10     0
#> 2     0     0
#> 3     0    20
#> 4     0     0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>